# Server crash mount XEN Server sata disk

Tags: xenserver, sata, server-crashes

Our Xen Server crashed and we try to mount the sata disk on an other linx to save the VM's. But unfortunately we are unlucky because the only thing we see is a lot of strange LV mounts.
When we do an `lvdisplay` we get the following output

```
[15:28:44] xxxxx: --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VG_XenStorage-38426a76-020b-9531-7c7e-4efdf4dc35fb/VHD-ae139547-d1af-4f54-bffe-a691593f1d92
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-38426a76-020b-9531-7c7e-4efdf4dc35fb
  LV UUID                FV5auY-3HHI-hCxk-niuf-08h1-ckmW-e6WueC
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                20.05 GiB
  Current LE             5132
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

Can any expert help, we are pretty lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this article from Citrix support that will instruct you to recover your crashed server.

[Reinstalling Xenserver and Preserving Virtual Machines on the Local Disk(s)](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX119905)

Comment: Thanks a great link. We had luck after a few restarts the machine came back all of the sudden. We are moving now to kvm anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sor far, it seems to me that it can only be achieved using another Xenserver host.

References: [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/291277/how-can-i-mount-a-xenserver-vhd-from-an-iscsi-sr-in-ubuntu) / [Citix Forums](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1475351)